# How to Hide Android WebView Notifications?

Tags: javascript, android, android-layout, android-webview

I am using 8 - 10 different WebViews in one layout and loading different content in each WebView.

While loading Webview shows different messages like "Loading.." "Processing.." etc.

[image]

Is there any way to hide these notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `HttpClient` to get the webpage's html code and then use `WebView.loadData` to load the entire page into WebView.

```
private class exampleHttpTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
    public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is, String charset) throws IOException {
        if (is != null) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, charset));
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
            return writer.toString();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        String r = "";
        try {
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://google.com"); // replace with the url
            HttpResponse hr = hc.execute(get);

            if(hr.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                InputStream is = hr.getEntity().getContent();
                r = convertStreamToString(is, "UTF-8");
            } else {
                r = "Error";
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view); // replace web_view with the webView id
        wv.loadData(result, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

}
```

Then call `new exampleHttpTask().exec()` to load the webpage.

Comment: This will work with a webpage (connect to the internet) but doesn't work when you want to load a page from your assets. See my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17145969/1031312

Comment: @Ozzy I have similar problem of loading from assests and avoiding flickering with mulitple webviews .Did you find any solution ?