# Remote button click (cgi script running)

Tags: android, html, web

I have a web device with switching capability. When I click on device own web page the certain output is change state.
I'd like to create an Android app what can manage this device on web. I'd would click on my app a button, and this event is run on device, click a button on device web page. 
This is the code on device web page:

```
<td width="130px"><input type="button"style="width:90px;"onclick="newAJAXCommand('leds.cgi?led=2');"value="Relé 1"/></td>
```

I have an idea of Android app, but I don't know how can I run this query (or create click event)?

The device: `http://91.137.148.13:8000/switch.htm`

Please, help.

Regards,
Gyula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the button on the webpage, the browser will send to a request to a specified url ( `http://91.137.148.13:8000/leds.cgi?led=0` ). So you can send a request to this url when user clicked the button in your Android app.

```
private class exampleHttpTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is, String charset) throws IOException {
    if (is != null) {
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, charset));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return writer.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    String r = "";
    try {
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://91.137.148.13:8000/leds.cgi?led=0");
        HttpResponse hr = hc.execute(get);

        if(hr.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            InputStream is = hr.getEntity().getContent();
            r = convertStreamToString(is, "UTF-8");
        } else {
            r = "Error";
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.d("WEB", result);
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
}

}
```

(the code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915354/how-to-hide-android-webview-notifications))
and when the onClick event is triggered, run

`new exampleHttpTask().exec()`

Comment: Thank you very much David. I'm gonna test it. Regards, Gyula

Comment: David, I have tested a link http://91.137.148.13:8000/leds.cgi?led=2 with a web browser, and its worked. You solved my problem. Thank you very much. Rgeards, Gyula